# Audio from one android phone to another

Tags: bluetooth, music, headphones

I have an old oneplus 6t I am using to play music as it is rooted and using Viper4Android to get better equalisation

At the same time, my main phone is a galaxy fold 4 and I would like to have my earbuds connected to this phone (so if I get a call I can take on earbuds etc) but receive music from my Oneplus

Anyone have any ideas or done something like this before?

Comment: [Set up Multipoint headphones on your devices](https://support.google.com/android/answer/12374042?hl=en) is probably what you are looking for. [More info](https://www.soundguys.com/how-to-bluetooth-multipoint-headphones-set-up-62931/)

Comment: As per [this](https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/support/wireless-headphones-bluetooth-headphones/wf-c500/articles/00230558) your headphones support multipoint. I haven't used this feature so can't confirm

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is not designed to be a network.  It is really for one device. It is hard enough to get more than one device working on one phone.  They take turns to connect.

Although you can pair a device to more than one phone, you can only receive from one source.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for your comment. Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way. Is there a way of doing this wirelessly, this device will always have network connectivity as it joins my hotspot and I have unlimited data. If not, can a Bluetooth device like earbuds connect to 1 phone for audio and 1 phone for just calls, and switch when needed?  My earbuds are Sony WF-c500